# PostgreSQL: COUNT() rows using 2-level joins with ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY active

Tags: postgresql, drupal, group-by, count, drupal-8

#### The problem

I am having trouble writing a functional query counting result rows with a 2-level join.

#### The database tables

I have the following (simplified) tables (the environment being developed in is Drupal 8 btw, using the database service):

**The `nodes` table:**

`id`          - numeric id
`title`       - varchar

**Example entries:**

```
id   title
1    My first article
2    My second article
3    My third article
```

**The `comments` table:**

`cid`         - numeric id
`entity_type` - varchar, the commented entity
`entity_id`   - numeric id, containing a reference
`status`      - int, 0 for unpublished, 1 for published
`comment`     - text

**Example entries:**

```
cid   entity_type   entity_id   status   comment
1     node          1           1        foo
2     node          1           1        bar
3     comment       1           1        baz
4     node          1           0        spam/foul language/whatever
5     node          2           1        yeeeha
```

#### Description of the data structure

"Nodes" can be commented. The comments then get stored in, well, the "comments" table. For each comment there is a dedicated row containing the id of the comment, the entity type commented (can be "node" and "comment") and the id of the commented entity. And comments can also be commented as well - these "replies" get stored in the "comments" table as well, thus these entries therefore contain "comment" as the entity_id and the id of the comment replied to.

I now would like to get the following result with a single query:

```
id    title                comments
1     My first article     3
2     My second article    1
3     My third article     0
```

The `comments` should contain the sum of all published comments and published replies to the given node. So, if a node is directly commented twice, and one of these comments got also commented on, the `comments` count should state `3`. (Note: atm "replies" to comments cannot be replied to, so there is just a 3-level environment here (`node` < `comment` < `comment`)).

#### The database in use:

The database in use is PostgreSQL 9.6 with `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` active.

#### What I tried

I've now already spent several hours trying to query the data with queries which pretty much all look similar to the following (using Drupal's database service `select` interface):

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, COUNT(c.cid)+COUNTr.cid) AS comments
FROM nodes n
LEFT JOIN comments c
ON c.type = "node" AND n.id = c.entity_id AND c.status = 1
LEFT JOIN comments r
ON r.type = "comment" AND c.id = r.entity_id AND r.status = 1
GROUP BY n.id, n.title, c.entity_id, r.entity_id
```

But for the life of me I just can't figure out the correct way of writing the query. My basic idea is to select the base table nodes, left join the first stage of comments on this and then again left join the replies to the first join. But it seems that my database has other ideas about my queries... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

I really hope there is someone out there that can get me back on track. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to read all this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is quite good. You just need to count distinct values at the first level, and to properly handle `NULL` values. Also, you want to group on columns coming for `nodes`, not from `comments`.

```
select 
    n.id,
    n.title,
    coalesce(count(distinct c1.cid), 0) + coalesce(count(c2.cid), 0) "comments"
from nodes n
left join comments c1 
    on  c1.entity_id = n.id  
    and c1.entity_type = 'node'
    and c1.status = 1
left join comments c2 
    on c2.entity_id = c1.cid  
    and c2.entity_type = 'comment'
    and c2.status = 1
group by n.id, n.title
```

This **[demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/44ga2tpZJgwSVXd8YvCxs8/1)** with your sample data returns:

```
| id  | title             | comments |
| --- | ----------------- | -------- |
| 1   | My first article  | 3        |
| 2   | My second article | 1        |
| 3   | My third article  | 0        |
```

Comment: Hi @GMB! First, let me thank you for your help! I've tried your suggestion, but it seems that something is a bit off in my actual implementation.  

See the actual generated query from Drupal in [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/mP2FCuKM). Problem with this is that actually the same node appears multiple times in the result set

Comment: Plus, I have no choice but to groupBy comments as well - as initially stated, ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY is in effect.

Comment: @Chris: I am not able to access the pastebin link. However, I made a few fixes to the query (missing conditions `status = 1`) and tested it in a fiddle. It does return the expected results now. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Chris: the rule that `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` enforces is: every non-aggregated column must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. There is no need to include columns of the `comments` table in the query since they are appear in aggregation expressions.

Comment: Oh, man! @GMB, I am SO sorry. My reply to your answer was based on a simple typo I made while trying out your suggestion. Instead of grouping entity_id I made the mistake and grouped cid - no wonder the same node got listed multiple times! THANK YOU, your help got me back on the road!

Answer (score 3):

First of all lets understand what you have written and missed - In the query you missed a ( after count in the first line.

Secondly you were doing group by with additional "r.entity_id" which is not required and it segregates the result.

Third order by the result by node id in ascending order.

Please use below query and mark the answer correct if it helps you.

```
SELECT n.id, n.title, COUNT(c.cid)+COUNT(r.cid) AS comments
FROM nodes n
 left JOIN comments c
ON c.entity_type = 'node' AND n.id = c.entity_id AND c.status = 1
 left JOIN comments r
ON r.entity_type = 'comment' AND c.cid = r.entity_id AND r.status = 1
GROUP BY n.id, n.title, c.entity_id 
order by n.id asc
```

Comment: Hi @Bipin Kumar! Thanks for your efforts to help me! :-) I understand the remarks you made, they are of great value for me and help me to understand the joins better! GMB just was some minutes quicker with his reply and his answer also helped me solve my problem. But I really appreciate the time you took to read my question and provide useful help!